# Preventing dropdown from hiding without JavaScript

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu

An onClick and hover dropdown menu in pure CSS (no JavaScript) displays the items at first, but the menu doesn't stay open when I put my mouse over the dropdown items (but it does stay open onClick).

Here it is:

```
.acn-menu {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.label_openclose {
  display: none;
}

.menu-tabs {
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 320px) {
  .menu-tabs {
  position: absolute;
  }
}

.menu-tabs .elem {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 20px;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 70px;
  background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
  color: white;
}

.menu-check {
  display: none;
}


label {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.label_openclose {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  min-height: 50px;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:block;
}

.menu-tabs .elem {
  line-height: initial;
  float: initial;
  height: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-top: 0px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu-check:checked~.menu-tabs .elem {
  height: 25px;
  color: white;
  border-top: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.label_openclose:hover~.menu-tabs .elem {
  border-top: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  height: 25px;
}
```

Here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lwjvwcva/

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a rule that tells the browser to show `.menu-tabs` while hovering on it, so I added this rule:

```
 .label_openclose~.menu-tabs:hover .elem {
  border-top: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  height: 25px;
}
```

check the [updated fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwjvwcva/3/).
hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

In order for the submenu to remain open, the item where the submenu sits INSIDE needs to be the one selected on hover. In this case .acn-menu or .nav (I used .nav in my code). To make the hover submenu stay open, I removed and added a few lines in the css:

Removed:

```
.label_openclose:hover~.menu-tabs .elem {
    border-top: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    height: 25px;
}
```

Added:

```
.nav .menu-tabs {
    display:none;
}

.nav:hover  .menu-tabs {
    display:block;
}

.menu-tabs .elem {
    height:25px;
    border-top: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
```